# AR & MA order from the ACF & PACF plots

Tags: time-series, arima, acf-pacf

[image]I am running a TS model & below are my ACF & PACF plots... In theory if the ACF plot is significant after Pth lag & PACF shows some geometric decay we can infer it is a MA series but my output is a little confusing where it doesnt follow any geometric decay for the PACF plot & also ACF is significant after 0th lag..How can I infer the model parameters/orders from this plot. Please advise.[ACF Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNhBi.png)
[image: ACF Plot]

[image: PACF Plot]

Answer (score 0):

Your acf and pacf plot is ambiguous. The paradigm you are trying to follow to identify the SARIMA model sometimes works when 
     1) there are no one-time pulses in the data
     2) there are no seasonal pulses in the data
     3) there are no level/step shifts in the data
     4) there are no local trends in the data
     5) the underlying (waiting to be discovered ) 
        model generates errors that has constant 
        variance
     6) the underlying model has constant 
        parameters over time.

A more robust paradigm/procedure to follow is suggested here

https://autobox.com/pdfs/ARIMA%20FLOW%20CHART.pdf

If you post your data , I will try and help further.

Comment: Thank you. Added decomp plot for more insights about series..hope this will help you comprehending the series..

Comment: add your data ... that will help the comprehension ... graphs and stuff are merely suggestive .